# How to update maven project for new chromedriver/selenium with all dependencies

Tags: selenium, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

With new version of Chromedriver (76) i couldnt use class `Actions` with `moveToElement` method.

From what i found out i had to update selenium also. But when i update selenium, ive got err:

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: 
>   class steps.MainHooks doesn't have an empty constructor. If you need
>   DI, put cucumber-picocontainer on the classpath

Then i updated appium, fluentlenium and so on and so on..

So my question is, what are right versions of dependecies for newest selenium? I am using Fluentlenium, Cucumber, Junit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selenium latest version you can use 3.1XX.X

Made updated version required the dependent dependencies. which can be seen in Compile Dependencies section or in IDE you can go to the pom of selenium, where you can see dependency required for them.

you can see the version on the below URL https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the same version of cucumber for the cucumber-picocontainer. Then you must add to CLASSPATH in EnviromentsSetting of Windows, the path to your cucumber-picocontainer-version.jar located in your .m2 repository, for example "C:\Users\Usuario.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-picocontainer\5.7.0*". Finally, restart the IDE for take the changes. You can check is your CLASSPATH is available in your IDE console, with the command: set CLASSPATH.